# Adding boxes (div) in html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add boxes with separate content in html/css.  Like in this wireframe mockup: [Wireframe Mockup](https://wireframe.cc/rnOXFK).  Newer to coding so appreciate the help!

Comment: Start for example here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest using drag and drop plugins from Wordpress.
Example could be Livecomposer. its very starter-friendly :)

OBS: This is just a quick-fix.

I still recommend you to read a bit about css and html